# How to insert a d3.js-shaped graph into Neo4J

Tags: javascript, neo4j, cypher

I have a JSON file I used with d3.js to display a forced directed graph. It's shaped like this:

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {"username": "crocodile", "id": 1},
        {"username": "TooSmart4U", "id": 2},
        {"username": "WTF12", "id": 44},
...
    ],
    "links": [
        {"source": 1, "target": 70, "action": "knows"},
        {"source": 4, "target": 20, "action": "knows"},
        {"source": 21, "target": 370, "action": "knows"},
...
    ]
}
```

I tried the following code (using Cypher to execute the query):

```
const {nodes, links} = require('./graph.json');

const statement = `
    UNWIND $nodes as user
    MERGE (u:User {username: user.username, id: user.id})
`;

const statement2 = `
    UNWIND $links as transactions
    FOREACH (t in transactions | MERGE (source:User {id: t.source}) MERGE (source)-[:KNOWS]->(target:User {id: t.target}))
`;
try {
    let result = await cypher(statement, {nodes});
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    result = await cypher(statement2, {links});
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
catch(ex) {
    console.error(ex);
}
```

The result is: all the nodes are inserted, but the relationships are not correct. I must be missing something in statement 2.

**Question:** what am I missing, and is it possible to do insert the entire graph with a single statement?

**Bonus:** right now, I have a single relation type (KNOWS). How do I make that a variable as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it, with 2 statements:

```
const statement = `
    UNWIND $nodes as user
    CREATE (u:User {id: user.id, username: user.name})
`;
const statement2 = `
    UNWIND $links as transaction
    WITH transaction.source AS sourceId, transaction.target AS targetId
    MATCH (source:User {id: sourceId}), (target:User {id: targetId})
    CREATE (source)-[:KNOWS]->(target)
`;
```

Would still love to find a way to do it in one statement, or find a better way to upload the graph, but this works.